# How to get my APP_KEY and SECRET_KEY for Dropbox sync?

Tags: android, synchronization, dropbox-api

I'm trying to build in the opportunity to sync my application's `*.csv` files with desirable `dropbox` account. What I've done so far:

1. Permissions and `com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity` in manifest
2. Signed my app with my `release-key-store`
3. Implemented some code to check `dropbox service`

The problem is that I can't understand where do I get APP_KEY and SECRET_KEY for this matter?

When I try to launch the app I'm getting this:

```
05-22 12:31:54.762: E/AndroidRuntime(5587):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.initNativeLib(CoreAccountManager.java:109)

05-22 12:31:54.762: E/AndroidRuntime(5587):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.CoreAccountManager.<init>(CoreAccountManager.java:89)

05-22 12:31:54.762: E/AndroidRuntime(5587):     at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.getInstance(DbxAccountManager.java:112)
```

Any clue what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer, you should lend to
[register_your_app_page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apply?cont=/developers/apps) first and you will get you keys there.

And don't forget to copy all libs provided with dropbox sdk in order to avoid init problems.

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:**
Sign in new Dropbox [Account here](https://www.dropbox.com/login), Create your Dropbox [APP HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/login?cont=https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create)

**Step 2:**
There are 2 options available creating a app,  Drops-in App &  Dropbox API App. You have to select **Dropbox API app** and give the name of your app.

**step 3:**
Go to [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/login?cont=https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) and select your created app. Under settings tab you can see the APP_KEY(App key) and SECRET_KEY(App secret)

Comment: This is a more straightforward answer than the currently-accepted one, in my opinion, and it works (from ios, in my case, whose web interface on Dropbox does not seem to include the given link, annoyingly).